# Docker Hub - Node Repo - What OS is this running?

Tags: node.js, docker

I went here because it was referenced from [Node.js Docker docs](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/nodejs-docker-webapp/).

https://hub.docker.com/_/node/

So what OS is this image based on?  Ubuntu?  Other?  It's not clear to me, I'm new to docker.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pull the image

```
docker pull node:latest
```

then login and check the OS

```
docker run -ti node:latest bash
cat /etc/*release
```

Another way, follow its `Dockerfile`, for example, with tag of `5.3/wheezy/Dockerfile`

```
https://github.com/nodejs/docker-node/blob/87993b5bb5b47a6dfc9f27b553406a4cb60f7050/5.3/wheezy/Dockerfile
```

The first line is `FROM buildpack-deps:wheezy`,

Keep digging:

```
https://github.com/docker-library/buildpack-deps/blob/1845b3f918f69b4c97912b0d4d68a5658458e84f/jessie/scm/Dockerfile

FROM buildpack-deps:jessie-curl

https://github.com/docker-library/buildpack-deps/blob/a0a59c61102e8b079d568db69368fb89421f75f2/jessie/curl/Dockerfile

FROM debian:jessie
```

So The OS is `debian`.

Comment: is Debian commonly used or do most people use Ubuntu for example out there?  Also can't you use straight CentOS too instead of Ubuntu?  I'm new to this.

Comment: you can get the ranks from many websites, here is one of them : http://distrowatch.com/dwres.php?resource=popularity . If you need node to be built in ubuntu, you needn't stick on office docker image, you can search in hub.docker.com or build one by yourself.